# Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies KMM

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a project in Android Studio for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) app using Kotlin. I am able to successfully run and build. However, when I open the project in Android Studio, I see the same error in many of the gradle project files .

The error is:

```
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinSourceSet'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Error:
[build.gradle.kts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrnhR.png)

When I open the Project Structure are three Suggestions:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLC4x.png)

However, What is shown first when I open the Project Structure is the Module **shared** which does not have **Source Compatibility** neither **Target Compatibility**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyd1J.png)

I have try to change the JavaVersion from **VERSION_1_8** to **VERSION_11**

[Android Studio Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment › Build Tools › Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA2On.png)

Comment: Have you tried invalidating caches and restarting? I've come across this error in Intellij before. Also check `project structure -> project` with and make sure your sdk and language level is set properly.

Comment:  Invalidating caches did the trick. I should have tried before post this question.
Thank you, Yogesh.